# @each loop over Map doesn't replace variable with value but prints variable name instead in SASS

Tags: css, angular, loops, sass

I have some colors in a map:

```
$colors: (
  a: #fff,
  b: #000,
)
```

Now I want to create CSS variables from that map:

```
:root {
  @each $name, $color in $colors {
    @debug($color);
    --color-#{$name}: $color;
  }
}
```

This looks pretty much like the textbook example. It does indeed create variables and debug shows the correct values (like `#fff`). Unfortunately in the CSS it comes out like:

```
--color-a: $color;
--color-b: $color;
```

What did I wrong?

---

PS: This happens on an Angular 8 project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use interpolation syntax also for `$color`:

```
$colors: (
  a: #fff,
  b: #000,
);

:root {
  @each $name, $color in $colors {
    --color-#{$name}: #{$color};
  }
}
```

Your result:

```
:root {
  --color-a: #fff;
  --color-b: #000;
}
```

**Edit:**
*why it is needed here?*

That's a very good question, cause I really didn't know *why*. So I did some research and I found this interesting doc=> https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars where is written:

> To provide maximum compatibility with plain CSS, more recent versions
>   of Sass require SassScript expressions in custom property values to be
>   written within interpolation. Interpolation will also work for older
>   Sass versions, and so is recommended for all stylesheets.

So the difference is because you are using custom property values (`--color-a`) and not a normal CSS property like `content`

Comment: Thank you for finding that explanation. I can't upvote again, but this is very helpful.

Comment: It was really interesting also for me to find the explanation! We did a good job! ;-)